# ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: viewPath

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Controller
controller code below to upload file

```
    [HttpPost("Index")]
    public IActionResult Index(Airport file)
    {
        // first step is to import the excel file which is what this line of code below is doing

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string filePath = null;



            if (file.AirportFile != null)
            {

                string UploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Airports");
                filePath = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + file.AirportFile.FileName;
                string theFilePath = Path.Combine(UploadsFolder, filePath);
                file.AirportFile.CopyTo(new FileStream(theFilePath, FileMode.Create));

                Airport newFile = new Airport
                {
                    AirportFilePath = filePath,
                };

                Console.WriteLine(newFile);

                // then we are gonna implement a connection string using microsoft.ace.oledb

                // also once the file have been retrieved into a variable i named tableName, i will then create an OleDb command object and pass the select query and the connection string to it

                string excelConnectionString = @"Provider='Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';Data Source='" + UploadsFolder + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1'";
                OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

                //getting excel sheet name
                excelConnection.Open();
                string tableName = excelConnection.GetSchema("Tables").Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                //then we close it
                excelConnection.Close();


                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + tableName + "]", excelConnection);

                excelConnection.Open();

                // here i am creating an OleDbDataReader that will all the records of the file

                OleDbDataReader theReader;
                theReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                // once the importing process begins, i do create a variable called hugecopy and set it to be the SQL DB table name to its destination table name, and then thru the hugecopy.columnmappings.add, i will be able to map thru my db

                SqlBulkCopy hugeCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString);

                hugeCopy.DestinationTableName = "Weather";


                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "Id");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Ident", "Ident");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("type", "type");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("name", "name");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("latitude_degrees", "latitude_degrees");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("longitude_degrees", "longitude_degrees");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("elevation_feet", "elevation_feet");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("continent", "continent");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("iso_region", "iso_region");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("municipality", "municipality");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("schedule_service", "schedule_service");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("gps_code", "gps_code");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("iata_code", "iata_code");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("local_code", "local_code");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("home_link", "home_link");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("wikipedia_link", "wikipedia_link");
                hugeCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("keywords", "keywords");

                hugeCopy.WriteToServer(theReader);
                excelConnection.Close();



            }

            // ViewBag.Result = "Success";


        }


        ViewBag.Result = "Success";
```

Models

namespace air_traffic_weather.Models
{
public class Airport
{

```
    [Key]

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [FileExt(Allow = ".xls,.xlsx", ErrorMessage = "Only excel file")]
    public IFormFile AirportFile { get; set; }

    public string AirportFilePath { get; set; }

    public string Ident { get; set; }

    public string type { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public int latitude_degrees { get; set; }

    public int longitude_degrees { get; set; }

    public int elevation_feet { get; set; }

    public string continent { get; set; }

    public string iso_region { get; set; }

    public string municipality { get; set; }

    public string schedule_service { get; set; }

    public string gps_code { get; set; }

    public string iata_code { get; set; }

    public string local_code { get; set; }

    public string home_link { get; set; }

    public string wikipedia_link { get; set; }

    public string keywords { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime Updated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

}

Views
code for my index.cshtml is below

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="import to DB" class=btn-btn-primary />

</form>
```

that is what i have so far and i keep having this error or problem. Any suggestion or ideas will be of great use , i have been stuck at this for hours.

Comment: we need to see full listing of your controller action. I suspect your problem is in the last line and you did not include it here.

Comment: hey @trailmax thanks for reaching out but i finally found out what the problem was coming from, which was exactly in my last line of code like you assumed and it was in my return view statement. Thanks again

Comment: Good stuff. Do you mind posting your solution here for future generations?

Comment: Only could find one question re `ViewPath` and the user never shared the solution, great!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the view contains a Partial tag with empty name!

```
<partial name="" />  <!--  -->
```